# users prompts with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I have multiple threads running and doing their thing in the 'background'. At a point in the program, user input (through a set of prompts) is required to gather information for the program to continue doing its thing. This will happen multiple times throughout the program. The way I currently do it works but is susceptible to issues. How do I 'assign' only one/the first thread to handle the user prompts without chance of the other threads spamming the user with the same prompts?

What I currently have is: (note: firstThread is a global)

```
    prbsMutex.acquire()
    if (firstThread == True):
        self.userPrompt()
        # set to false so other threads don't reprompt the user after lock is released
        firstThread = False
    prbsMutex.release()

    # ....code to do things with user input...

    #shortly after I reset the flag for when it loops back again
    firstThread = False
```

I want a way to say, 'Thread 1 is the only thread that should be prompting the user while the other threads WAIT FOR IT TO FINISH', but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Create a "user prompting and input" thread to handle all user input. Have the other threads in your script communicate with it through a `Queue` or control concurrent access to its getting input via a `Lock` mutex.

Comment: Could you tell me what the difference between this question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865825/user-prompts-with-multithreading where I answered you?

Comment: Sure. The previous question asked how to efficiently have the first thread to reach that line prompt the user in a loop (so it can possibly be a different thread that prompts the user each time). This question asks how can I designate one thread to prompt the user each time it reaches that line in a loop. I've played around with threading.current_thread().ident but I feel like there should be a better way.